# Return Custom Object

Tags: c#, powershell

```
script += string.Format(@"$Processes = Get-Process -ComputerName {0} | Sort-Object CPU -desc | Select-Object;", remoteMachineName);
script += @"$ProcessArray= @();";
script += @"foreach ($process in $Processes) {";
script += @"$ProcessNamesss = $process.ProcessName;";
script += @"$objAverage = New-Object System.Object;";
script += @"$objAverage | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Name -value $ProcessNamesss;";
script += @"$ProcessArray +=$objAverage; } ";
script += "$ProcessArray;";
```

My code runs fine. but it returns 109 results. It should return one result with array that contains 109 objects? which i have filled in foreach loop?
How can i return only that array `$ProcessArray`?

Comment: `"$ProcessArray;"` -> `",$ProcessArray;"`

Comment: Check the title how m i suppose to find that :S